# Let $ f(x) $ has a vertical asymptote $ x=0 $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ f(x) $ has a vertical asymptote $ x=0 $. If $ f'(x) >0 \ \ for \ x<0 \ \ and \ \ f'(x) <0 \ \ for \ x>0 $ ,

then say  true or false ?

(i) $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=+\infty $

**Answer:** **I got $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=+\infty $  to be false by drawing the graph. But not sure . Can I get any help ?**

Answer (score 1):

Since for negative values of x the function is increasing (f '(x) > 0 for x < 0), clearly the limit as we approach zero from below, or $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-}f(x)$ = $+\infty$.

Now for positive values of x the function is decreasing (f '(x) < 0 for x > 0), so if we imagine taking smaller values of x for positive x values, the value of f(x) can only increase, thus the limit as we approach zero from above, or $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)= +\infty$.

Since the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)$ = $+\infty$ and the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-}f(x)=+\infty$ then it must be that the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)$ = $+\infty$.